# Cannot populate fields in express and Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models Post and Users and I want to populate the posts fields

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    text: { 
        type: String 
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }
})
```

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String, 
    }
})
```

```
router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        let joe = new User({username: "joe"})
        await joe.save()
        
        let postText = {text: "my name is joe", author: joe._id}
        let postByJoe = new Post(postText)
        await postByJoe.save()

        let users = User.find().populate('author') 
        res.json({users})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
        res.json(error.message)
    }
    
})
```

The problem is that I get an error and I don't know what to make of it. I'm not sure at all what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated

"Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes the circle"

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your schema is different, you can only populate the  `Schema.Types.ObjectId` field in your schema. Seems you are trying to populate the author field of the Post model.

Replace this line `let users = User.find().populate('author')`  with this `let users = Post.find().populate('user')  Your code should be like the one below:`

```
router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
try {
    let joe = new User({username: "joe"})
    await joe.save()
    
    let postText = {text: "my name is joe", author: joe._id}
    let postByJoe = new Post(postText)
    await postByJoe.save()

   let data = await Post.find().populate('user') 
    // map through the object returned
    const users = data.map((user) => user)
    res.json({users})
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
    res.json(error.message)
}

})
```

Read more about mongoose population [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/mongoose-population/)

Comment: A big problem was that I also wasn't using await. I had changed the schema and used user instead of author but I still had the error. Then I used await and the error went away. Thank you so much though